# Extract specific column from string in C

Tags: c, linux

I have a text file containing multiple columns of integers. Sample file is as:

```
Col1    Col2   Col3  Col4
Col1    Col2   Col3  Col4
.
.
.
Col1    Col2   Col3  Col4
```

I am able to read the file line by line. Now if I want to read Col3 from each line read, how would I be able to do this and store it in some int variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int a[5];
```

Use

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
fscanf(fp,"%*d %*d %d %*d",&a[i]);
```

Else

1. Read a line using `fgets()`
2. Break the line using `strtok()` using proper delimiter.
3. Use `atoi()` on the 3rd token to convert it to an integer.
4. Store the value